# Adding different projects in a solution to their own git branches

Tags: github, branch

6 projects in a solution all live on master. Im using mvvm with a repository
I would like to have a Data Model branch, a view model branch, a repository branch, etc.

I have created the repo on git hub, created a branch that was not master and added the project on the requisite branch. When I am done, projects all are still on master, other branches exist but are empty showing only the blank solution I started with

Answer (score 0):

In your local clone, you need to:

- create your new branch from your current master (which has all the files)
- git rm all the files which are not part of what you want to keep in that branch
- commit and push (git push -u origin newBranch)

Repeat (get back to master, which *still* has all the files) for each new branch.

Finally, go back one last time to master, git rm the files you don't need anymore (because they have been referenced by your new branches), add, commit and push.